# Saving post tags using a HABTM relationship

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a `Post` model and `Tag` model which are both set up correctly with a HABTM relationship. I also have a table in my database called `posts_tags` which is named correctly as per the naming conventions.

However, I can't for the life of me work out how to save tags along with a post. On my "Add Post" page I have this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Post'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Post.title'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Post.body'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Tag.name'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Post.slug'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Publish'); ?>
```

which calls this action on submit:

```
public function add() {
    if($this->request->is('post')) {            
        if($this->Post->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Post published!');
            $this->redirect('/');
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Post unable to be saved!');
        }
    }

    $this->set('pageTitle', 'Compose new blog post');
}
```

The post saves but not the tag or the relationship between the post and tag, and Cake gives me no error or warning. What do I have to do to get Cake to save the tag along with the post and make the required relationship?

Edit: here's a dump of what's in `$this->request->data` which is being saved to the database using `saveAll()`:

```
array(
    'Post' => array(
        'title' => 'Blog post',
        'body' => 'Testing this post',
        'slug' => 'Blog-post'
    ),
    'Tag' => array(
        'name' => 'test-tag'
    )
)
```

Comment: does the tag save in your `tags` table?

Comment: Nope, neither the tag nor the relationship in `posts_tags`.

Comment: I've edited the question to give you the output of `$this->request->data`.

Answer (score 0):

If your relationship for Tag to Post is hasMany, try changing:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Tag.name'); ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Tag.0.name'); ?>
```

Comment: It's not `hasMany`, it's `hasAndBelongsToMany`. But I will try that :)

Comment: Nope - still no change. The post gets inserted but the tag does not :(